# How to iterate over a range and an array of data and set the iterated array values until there's no data using GAS?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, google-apps-script, google-sheets

This may seem simple to you, but well....here I am.

The code below sets apparently the last value `Mangas` to all cells in the `rangeList` , while it should set Alca to A10, Mangas to F10 and stop, because there are only 2 elements.

```
const rngs = ["A10", "F10", "J10", "A12", "F12", "J12"];
const rangeList = sheetVendSobEnc.getRangeList(rngs).getRanges();
let coresPartes = ["Alca", "Mangas"]
  for (let a = 0; a < rangeList.length; a++) {
    for (let n = 0; n < coresPartes.length; n++) {
      rangeList[a].setValue(coresPartes[n])
    }
  }
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: First there are no '' in coresPartes so not sure what that does.  Second there are 2 elements in coresPartes but you don't change the range for the second element so you only get "Mangas" in each range.  What are you expecting?

Comment: Just updated the question, @TheWizEd. In that case, why is this not changing the range in each iteration? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is this?

```
const rngs = ["A10", "F10", "J10", "A12", "F12", "J12"];
const rangeList = sheetVendSobEnc.getRangeList(rngs).getRanges();
let coresPartes = ["Alca", "Mangas"]
  for (let a = 0; a < rangeList.length; a++) {
    if( coresPartes[a] ===  undefined ) return;  // or break i'm no sure
    rangeList[a].setValue(coresPartes[a])
  }
}
```

Comment: Exactly that! Thank you! I thought I'd have to iterate over both of them...